# AWS-Amplify is not updating my index.html file in public folder

Tags: build, aws-amplify, continuous-deployment

I've changed the meta tags in my index.html. But this is not updating in amplify. I have a git connection that auto-builds...why is not pulling these changes from git when it builds and deploys?

Comment: Did you get an answer? My index.html, head meta tag and public font folder files not updated either. They are not in S3